# Is it possible to use storySort for story variants?

Tags: javascript, storybook

I've got a storybook instance set up with some custom sorting added in order to ensure that the `docs` section appears at the top and is ordered correctly. However, it is now alphabetising *all* of the stories and their variations. This is annoying and I can't seem to change it using `storySort`, is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Here's an example of what it currently looks like:
[image: Screenshot of sidebar]

All of this is fine until you reach the `Button` story, as you can see, each variant has been added in alphabetical order instead of the order they are in on the page. Here is my `storySort` object, have I done something wrong here?

```js
storySort: {
      method: 'configure',
      includeName: true,
      order: [
        'Docs',
        [
          'Introduction',
          'Coding Guidelines',
          ['General'],
          '*',
          'Architectural Decisions',
          ['Introduction']
        ],
        'Atoms',
        'Molecules',
        'Organisms',
        'Pages'
      ]
    }
```

I've also tried it without adding `method` and `includeName` but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried adding `['*', ['Default', 'Primary', 'Secondary', 'Tertiary', 'Alternate']],` underneath each `Atoms`, `Molecules` and `Organisms` entries but that didn't seem to make a difference.